# SQL Query to C#

Tags: c#, sql

I am writing this query that I want to transition into C# but I get an error.

The error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
>
> Incorrect syntax near 'Products'.

Here is the query I am trying to run.

```
Select    
      [ID]
      ,[ProductTypeID]
      ,[SeriesID]
      ,[PartNumber]
      ,[Title]
      ,[SEOFriendlyURLTitle]
      ,[HTMLDescription]
      ,[HTMLValueAdded]
      ,[RoHSCompliant]
      ,[ULCompliant]
      ,[CECompliant]
      ,[Series]
      ,[BUSINESS_UNIT]
      ,[PACKAGING_TYPE]
      ,[PACK_QTY]
      ,[MOQ]
      ,[ORDER_MULTIPLE]
      ,[LEAD_TIME_WEEKS]
      ,[INTERNATIONAL_HARMONIZE_CODE]
      ,[ECCN_NUMBER]
      ,[COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN]
      ,[IS_PART_STATIC_SENSITIVE]
      ,[IS_PART_LEAD_PB_FREE]
      ,[MOISTURE_SENSITIVITY_LEVEL_MSL]
      ,[REGISTERABLE]
      ,[TAPE_WIDTH]
      ,[TAPE_MATERIAL]
      ,[QtyOnHand]
      ,[QtyOnSalesOrder]
      ,[QtyOnBackOrder]
      ,[ProductLine]
      ,[Reach138Compliant]
      ,[ConflictMinerals]
      ,[WebEnabled]
      ,[DateAdded]
      ,[UpdateDate]
      ,[Reviewed]
      ,[ReviewedBy]
      ,[Deleted]
      ,[Book]
      ,[CustomSort]
      ,[ONEK]
      ,[FIVEK]
      ,[TENK]
      ,[TWENTYFIVEK]   
      ,[Fifty]
      ,[OneHundred]
      ,[FiveHundred]                                 
FROM    Products.Products
Join
(SELECT Products.Prices.ProductID, 
    Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='ONEK',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS ONEK, 
    Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='FIVEK',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS FIVEK, 
    Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='TENK',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS TENK, 
    Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='TWENTYFIVEK',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS  TWENTYFIVEK,
    Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='Fifty',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS Fifty, 
    Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='OneHundred',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS OneHundred, 
    Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='FiveHundred',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS FiveHundred
FROM Products.Prices
GROUP BY Products.Prices.ProductID
) As pp
ON Products.Products.ID = pp.ProductID
```

Here is the query in C#:

```
y1.CommandText = "Select [ID], [PartNumber], [Book], [HTMLDescription], [HTMLValueAdded], [RoHSCompliant], [ULCompliant],[CECompliant], [Series], [BUSINESS_UNIT], [ONEK], [FIVEK], [TENK], [TWENTYFIVEK]" +
",[Fifty], [OneHundred], [FiveHundred], [PACKAGING_TYPE], [PACK_QTY], [MOQ], [ORDER_MULTIPLE], [LEAD_TIME_WEEKS], [INTERNATIONAL_HARMONIZE_CODE], [ECCN_NUMBER], [COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN]" +
",[IS_PART_STATIC_SENSITIVE], [IS_PART_LEAD_PB_FREE], [MOISTURE_SENSITIVITY_LEVEL_MSL], [REGISTERABLE], [TAPE_WIDTH], [TAPE_MATERIAL], [Reach138Compliant], [ConflictMinerals], [WebEnabled]" +
"FROM Products.Products" +
"Join" +
"(SELECT Products.Prices.ProductID," +
    "Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='ONEK',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS ONEK," +
    "Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='FIVEK',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS FIVEK," +
    "Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='TENK',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS TENK," +
    "Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='TWENTYFIVEK',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS  TWENTYFIVEK," +
    "Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='Fifty',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS Fifty," +
    "Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='OneHundred',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS OneHundred," +
    "Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='FiveHundred',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS FiveHundred" +
"FROM Products.Prices" +
"GROUP BY Products.Prices.ProductID" +
") As pp" +
"ON Products.Products.ID = pp.ProductID" +
"where partnumber like '6%'";
```

Please help and thank you.

Comment: You need to output the command text to the debug window and figure this out. I can see straight off you need to add a " " before `(SELECT` on line 6. This is just lazy.

Comment: please narrow down your code sample

Comment: try putting `@"your query here";` sign and you will be fine.

Comment: So you've got a syntax error. Did it occur to you to check the syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing **SPACES** in front of `FROM`, `Join`, `(SELECT` etc... So when they are being output you are seeing `FROM Products.ProductsJoin`. You also want to prefix with `@` to protect against escaping issue. To fix you want:

```
y1.CommandText = @"Select [ID], [PartNumber], [Book], [HTMLDescription], [HTMLValueAdded], [RoHSCompliant], [ULCompliant],[CECompliant], [Series], [BUSINESS_UNIT], [ONEK], [FIVEK], [TENK], [TWENTYFIVEK]" +
",[Fifty], [OneHundred], [FiveHundred], [PACKAGING_TYPE], [PACK_QTY], [MOQ], [ORDER_MULTIPLE], [LEAD_TIME_WEEKS], [INTERNATIONAL_HARMONIZE_CODE], [ECCN_NUMBER], [COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN]" +
",[IS_PART_STATIC_SENSITIVE], [IS_PART_LEAD_PB_FREE], [MOISTURE_SENSITIVITY_LEVEL_MSL], [REGISTERABLE], [TAPE_WIDTH], [TAPE_MATERIAL], [Reach138Compliant], [ConflictMinerals], [WebEnabled]" +
" FROM Products.Products" +
" Join" +
" (SELECT Products.Prices.ProductID," +
    "Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='ONEK',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS ONEK," +
    "Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='FIVEK',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS FIVEK," +
    "Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='TENK',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS TENK," +
    "Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='TWENTYFIVEK',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS  TWENTYFIVEK," +
    "Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='Fifty',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS Fifty," +
    "Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='OneHundred',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS OneHundred," +
    "Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='FiveHundred',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS FiveHundred" +
" FROM Products.Prices" +
" GROUP BY Products.Prices.ProductID" +
") As pp" +
" ON Products.Products.ID = pp.ProductID" +
" where partnumber like '6%'";
```

Comment: @Dunleyyy333 Great and glad I could help. Can you please click the TICK next to my answer so that people with similar problems can find the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take this segment as an example:

```
"FROM Products.Products" +
"Join" +
```

When these strings are concatenated, you get:

```
"FROM Products.ProductsJoin"
```

You need to include the spaces.

```
"FROM Products.Products " +
"Join" +
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [verbatim string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (`@`), copy your query and create it like:

```
      string query = 
      @"Select    
      [ID]
      ,[ProductTypeID]
      ,[SeriesID]
      ,[PartNumber]
      ,[Title]
      ,[SEOFriendlyURLTitle]
      ,[HTMLDescription]
      ,[HTMLValueAdded]
      ,[RoHSCompliant]
      ,[ULCompliant]
      ,[CECompliant]
      ,[Series]
      ,[BUSINESS_UNIT]
      ,[PACKAGING_TYPE]
      ,[PACK_QTY]
      ,[MOQ]
      ,[ORDER_MULTIPLE]
      ,[LEAD_TIME_WEEKS]
      ,[INTERNATIONAL_HARMONIZE_CODE]
      ,[ECCN_NUMBER]
      ,[COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN]
      ,[IS_PART_STATIC_SENSITIVE]
      ,[IS_PART_LEAD_PB_FREE]
      ,[MOISTURE_SENSITIVITY_LEVEL_MSL]
      ,[REGISTERABLE]
      ,[TAPE_WIDTH]
      ,[TAPE_MATERIAL]
      ,[QtyOnHand]
      ,[QtyOnSalesOrder]
      ,[QtyOnBackOrder]
      ,[ProductLine]
      ,[Reach138Compliant]
      ,[ConflictMinerals]
      ,[WebEnabled]
      ,[DateAdded]
      ,[UpdateDate]
      ,[Reviewed]
      ,[ReviewedBy]
      ,[Deleted]
      ,[Book]
      ,[CustomSort]
      ,[ONEK]
      ,[FIVEK]
      ,[TENK]
      ,[TWENTYFIVEK]   
      ,[Fifty]
      ,[OneHundred]
      ,[FiveHundred]                                 
FROM    Products.Products
Join
(SELECT Products.Prices.ProductID, 
    Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='ONEK',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS ONEK, 
    Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='FIVEK',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS FIVEK, 
    Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='TENK',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS TENK, 
    Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='TWENTYFIVEK',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS  TWENTYFIVEK,
    Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='Fifty',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS Fifty, 
    Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='OneHundred',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS OneHundred, 
    Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='FiveHundred',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS FiveHundred
FROM Products.Prices
GROUP BY Products.Prices.ProductID
) As pp
ON Products.Products.ID = pp.ProductID";
```

*(This will save you from figuring out errors in your concatenation, and would be more readable IMO)*

Comment: How do i do this then at the end of it  ON Products.Products.ID = pp.ProductID
Where Partnumber like '" + TextBox2.Text + "'";

Comment: @Dunleyyy333, **don't**.. Use Sql Parameter like `WHERE Partnumber like @partNumber` and later add that parameter. SEe: http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter